# My AJAX dropdown isn't pulling database options

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Building this form to later put into a larger form. The idea is for the first dropdown to be populated then the second is then populated depending on the first. Here is the form.php and the func.php. This is my first journey into AJAX. I know I'm missing something, but may be "code-blind".

**Form**

```
    <?php 
  include('db.php');
  include('func.php');
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chained Select Boxes using PHP, MySQL and jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
    $('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_2",
        drop_var: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax2('result_2', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax2(id, response) {
  $('#wait_2').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}

function finishAjax_tier_three(id, response) {
  $('#wait_2').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax_tier_four(id, response) {
  $('#wait_3').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">

    <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Manufacturer</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="wait_2" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_2" style="display: none;"></span> 
      <span id="wait_3" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_3" style="display: none;"></span> 

</form>
</p>
<p>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
    $drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3'];
    $drop_4 = $_POST['drop_4'];
    echo "You have a ";
    echo $drop." ".$drop_2." is selected from ".$drop_3."  ".$drop_4;
?>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#B5B5B5" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="250" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Manufacturer</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_2;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_3;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pressure</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_4;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
```

**Function**

```
    <?php

//     Page load dropdown results     //

function getTierOne()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM stmTrps ASC") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['Trap_Manufacturer'].'">'.$tier['Trap_Manufacturer'].'</option>';
        }

}


//     First selection results     //

if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_1" ) {
drop_1($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Trap_Manufacturer FROM stmTrps WHERE Trap_Manufacturer='$drop_var' ORDER BY Trap_Manufacturer") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Model</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['Trap_Model'].'">'.$drop_2['Trap_Model'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_2\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val(),
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_three('result_2', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}


//     Second selection results     //

if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_2" ) {
drop_2($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['drop_var2']);
}

function drop_2($drop_var, $drop_var2)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT size FROM stmTrps WHERE Trap_Manufacturer='$drop_var' AND Trap_Model='$drop_var2'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_3" id="drop_3">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Size</option>';

           while($drop_3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_3['size'].'">'.$drop_3['size'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val(),
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val(),
        drop_var3: $('#drop_3').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_four('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}


//     Second selection results     //

if(isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_3" ) {
drop_3($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['drop_var2'], $_GET['drop_var3']);
}
function drop_3($drop_var, $drop_var2, $drop_var3)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stmTrps WHERE Trap_Manufacturer='$drop_var' AND Trap_Model='$drop_var2' AND size='$drop_var3'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    echo '<select name="drop_4" id="drop_4">
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Pressure</option>';


           while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
                {
                if ($drop_4['accu'] != "") {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_4['accu'].'">'.$drop_4['accu'].'</option>';
                }
  }
    echo '</select> ';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
}

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: So... how exactly are you using ajax here? are you using jquery to make the ajax call? If its so, I don't see any $.POST or $.GET or $.getJSON in the code. take a look in here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Cheluis - I'm using `$_GET` here -  `if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_1" ) {
drop_1($_GET['drop_var']);
}`

Comment: $_GET is a server side variable, from PHP. $.get is from the html side of your page.

Comment: @Cheluis - I understand that. I'm lost on where I would put that in my form.php code.

Comment: sorry, i've just seen the $.get functions. whats "func" parameter on the $.get function? you need to check the documentation of the get function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/